# How to perform long division on polynomials.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{ 9x^6 - 4x^5 + 0 + 0 + 3x^2 + 0 - 1 }{ x^2 - 2x + 1 }$$

I know it starts with $\ { 9x^4 }$but the next two numbers are $\ { 14x^3 }$ $\ { 19x^2 }$. How do you come up with those two numbers?

How does $\ { -4x^5 + 18x^5 }$ equal $\ { 14x^3 }$

Comment: You can only place a zero when you are doing  synthetic division.Did you try the link I suggested yesterday?

Comment: You should really find a youtube (or otherwise) *video* on the topic. It's really pretty dynamic and doesn't exactly lend itself to pictures of sequential steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ 9 x^4 (x^2 - 2x + 1) = 9 x^6 - 18 x^5 + 9 x^4;  $$
so, our first partial quotient is $9x^4,$ and the first remainder is
$$  9 x^6 - 4 x^5 + 3 x^2 - 1 -  9 x^4 (x^2 - 2x + 1) = 14 x^5 - 9 x^4 + 3 x^2 - 1.$$

Next partial quotient is $14x^3$ as
$$ 14 x^3 (x^2 - 2x + 1) = 14 x^5 - 28 x^4 + 14 x^3;  $$ second remainder is 
$$ 14 x^5 - 9 x^4 + 3 x^2 - 1 -  14 x^3 (x^2 - 2x + 1) = 19 x^4 - 14 x^3 + 3 x^2 - 1.  $$

Next partial quotient is $19x^2$ as
$$ 19 x^2 (x^2 - 2x + 1) = 19 x^4 - 38 x^3 + 19 x^2;  $$ third remainder is 
$$ 19 x^4 - 11 x^3 + 3 x^2 - 1 - 19 x^2 (x^2 - 2x + 1) =  24 x^3 - 16 x^2 -1   $$

Next partial quotient is $24x$ as
$$ 24 x (x^2 - 2x + 1) = 24 x^3 - 48 x^2 + 24 x;  $$ fourth remainder is 
$$ 27 x^3 - 16 x^2 -1  - 27 x (x^2 - 2x + 1) = 32 x^2 - 24 x - 1.$$

Final partial quotient is $32$ as
$$ 32 (x^2 - 2x + 1) = 32 x^3 - 64 x^2 + 32 x;  $$ fifth and final remainder is 
$$32 x^2 - 24 x - 1 - 32 (x^2 - 2x + 1) = 40x -33.$$

TO CHECK!!
$$ \mbox{ORIGINAL} \; \; = \hspace{48mm} 9 x^6 - 4 x^5 + 3 x^2 - 1 $$
$$ (x^2 - 2  x + 1) ( 9  x^4 + 14  x^3 + 19  x^2 + 24  x + 32) = 9x^6 - 4x^5 + 3x^2 - 40x + 32 $$

Comment: Still confused, I understand half of what you said. I don't understand the remainder parts! That still doesn't answer my question either.

Comment: @user242559 since you are under my answer rather than the question, you need to start your comment with an at sign followed by W.Zlacki. Also, I seem to have made some arithmetic errors

Comment: Sorry Will Jagy, didn't mean to.

Comment: Wolffram alpha yeah I been there but they still don't tell me what I ask!

Comment: How does $\ { -4x^5 + 18x^5 }$ equal $\ { 14x^3 }$

Comment: @W.ZlackiThe remainder of  this type of long division always goes over what you are dividing by.For example, this problem, if it has a remainder would go over the $x^2-2x+1$.

Comment: @W Zlacki I found your problem. You forgot to change the negative $-18x^5$ to a positive. 18 +-4 is $14x^5$. $14x^3$ times $x^2$ equals $14x^5$, and so on.

Comment: @W.Zlacki recommend you get some kind of personal tutoring. I am actually not impressed with my ability, or anyone's, to teach students online here; there are just too many matters of context that can be mistaken in print, but fixed quickly and well by a tutor in person, especially by your actual teacher, perhaps after hours.

Comment: Where could I find a good tutor? Maybe a local university?

Comment: @user242559 thank you, so much. That really helped.

Comment: @user242559 you get the April award for mind-reading

Comment: Last one, how to deal with zeros. How does $\ { 0 + 9x^4 }$ equal $\ {19x^2}$

Comment: Do I add one to it?

Comment: I just seem not to be able to figure out the next one till I see it!

Comment: $\ { 0 - 9x^4 }$ equal $\ { 19x^2 }$ how?

Comment: Nvm I figured it out!

Answer (score 2):

One may also write
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{9x^6-4x^5+3x^2}{x^2-2x+1} &= \frac{9x^4(x^2-2x+1)+14x^5-9x^4+3x^2}{x^2-2x+1} 
\\\\&= 9x^4+ \frac{14x^3(x^2-2x+1)+19x^4-14x^3+3x^2}{x^2-2x+1} 
\\\\&= 9x^4+14x^3+\frac{19x^2(x^2-2x+1)+24x^3-19x^2}{x^2-2x+1} 
\\\\&= 9x^4+14x^3+19x^2+\frac{24x(x^2-2x+1)+29x^2}{x^2-2x+1} 
\\\\&=\cdots
\end{align}
$$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The effect of division can be expressed as

$$P(x)-Q(x)D(x)=R(x)$$ where $P$ is the dividend, $D$ the divisor, $Q$ the quotient and $R$ the remainder. The goal of the "game" is to make $R$ as small as possible.

As you say, the first term in the quotient is $9x^4$. Then you have

$$P(x)-9x^4D(x)=R'(x),$$

with $$R'(x)=( 9x^6 - 4x^5 + 0 + 0 + 3x^2 + 0 - 1)-9x^4(x^2 - 2x + 1)=14x^5-9x^4+3x^2-1.$$

Now you just repeat the process with $R'$ instead of $R$. The new term will be $14x^3$, and

$$R''(x)=P(x)-(9x^2+14x^3)(x^2 - 2x + 1)=R'(x)-14x^3(x^2 - 2x + 1)\\
=19x^4-14x^3+3x^2-1.$$

Then the next new term is $19x^2$, followed by $24x$ and $32$.

The process continues until the degree of the remainder drops below that of the divisor, as it becomes impossible to cancel the leading term.

In our case, $40x-33$.